# Yii extension XML Parsing Error: no element found

Tags: php, xml, yii, rss, yii-extensions

I'm using this [RSS extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/efeed/) and followed it's example from the documentation.

In my View

```
 Yii::import('ext.feed.*');
// RSS 2.0 is the default type
$feed = new EFeed();

$feed->title= 'Testing RSS 2.0 EFeed class';
$feed->description = 'This is test of creating a RSS 2.0 Feed';

$feed->setImage('Testing RSS 2.0 EFeed class','http://www.ramirezcobos.com/rss',
'http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/uploads/profile/photo-7106.jpg');

$feed->addChannelTag('language', 'en-us');
$feed->addChannelTag('pubDate', date(DATE_RSS, time()));
$feed->addChannelTag('link', 'http://www.ramirezcobos.com/rss' );

// * self reference
$feed->addChannelTag('atom:link','http://www.ramirezcobos.com/rss/');

$item = $feed->createNewItem();

$item->title = "first Feed";
$item->link = "http://www.yahoo.com";
$item->date = time();
$item->description = 'This is test of adding CDATA Encoded description <b>EFeed Extension</b>';
// this is just a test!!
$item->setEncloser('http://www.tester.com', '1283629', 'audio/mpeg');

$item->addTag('author', 'thisisnot@myemail.com (Antonio Ramirez)');
$item->addTag('guid', 'http://www.ramirezcobos.com/',array('isPermaLink'=>'true'));

$feed->addItem($item);

$feed->generateFeed();
Yii::app()->end();
```

In my controller

```
public function actionFeed()
{
    $this->renderPartial('feed');
}
```

In Firefox i get this error

```
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://localhost/dev/frontend/www/abc/bla/feed/
Line Number 1, Column 2: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-^
```

and in chrome

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

In the extension there is this function

```
public function generateFeed(){
        header("Content-type: text/xml");
        $this->renderHead();
        $this->renderChannels();
        $this->renderItems();
        $this->renderBottom();
    }
```

When i comment out `header("Content-type: text/xml");` there is NO error, but the page displays in html and all in 1 line. but when you view the source, the tags are ALL in place.

The 1st 2 lines look like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

change

`<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">` to

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

See the **question mark (?)** after tag

**Update:**

Your xml should be a string or inside single quotes like

```
<?php header("Content-type: application/xml"); 
echo  
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>RSS2 Feed</title>
<link>http://www.url.com/</link>
</channel>
</rss>';
?>
```

Comment: now i get this `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev/frontend/modules/abc/views/bla/feed.php on line 2` where `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is line 2. Line 1 is `<?php header("Content-type: application/xml"); ?>`

Comment: now i'm getting `XML or text declaration not at start of entity`